state variable does not update when passing updated value
Within my functional component
I have a state variable named inputList which takes a list of objects.
const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([{ word: "", meaning: "" }]);

I map on inputList to render two input fields named word & meaning along with add & remove buttons. Buttons can be used to add or remove multiple input fields.
PROBLEM is : whenever I remove fields, the text in those fields should also get removed from inputList data. But inputList does not update itself.
my render jsx contains following code:
{inputList.map((x, i) => {
                return (
                    <div key={i} className="flex w-full justify-center">
                        <input onChange={e => handleOnChange(e,i)} name="word" placeholder="Word"  type="text" />
                        <input onChange={e => handleOnChange(e,i)} name="meaning" placeholder="Meaning"  type="text" />
                        {
                            inputList.length !== 1 &&
                            <button onClick={(i)=>{handleRemoveClick(i)}} >Remove</button>                            
                        }

                    </div>
                )
            })}

the handler functions are :
    const handleAddClick = () => {
        setInputList([...inputList, { word: "", meaning: "" }]);
    }

    const handleOnChange = (e, i) => {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        const list = [...inputList];
        list[i][name] = value;
        setInputList(list);
    }

    const handleRemoveClick = index => {
        console.log(index);
        const list = [...inputList];
        list.splice(index, 1);
        console.log(list);
        setInputList(list);
        console.log(inputList);
    }

handleRemoveClick() console logs on removing c and d from given input fields:


I dont understand why handleOnChange(e, i) receives i as index from map function but handleRemoveClick(i) receives an unknown object as displayed in console.log

Should be ()=>{handleRemoveClick(i)} and not (i)=>{handleRemoveClick(i)}

@Konrad got it -- you're replacing i with the event:
<button onClick={(i)=>{handleRemoveClick(i)}} >Remove</button> 

It should be:
<button onClick={()=>{handleRemoveClick(i)}} >Remove</button> 

Or, for consistency
It should be:
<button onClick={(e)=>{handleRemoveClick(i)}} >Remove</button> 


thank you, now index i is ok but console log of inputList is still showing same results, using react dev tools on my browser I can see that inputList is getting updated properly but I think it takes too much time that even component re-renders before it updates(console.log also finishes before its updation).

Because the update is added to a queue. If you want to see the updated value, you have to defer your request: setInputList(list); setTimeout(() => console.log(inputList), 0);
